# Changing state of a list item component in a ListFragment

Tags: android, fragment, selector

I'm currently creating a custom ListView Fragment based on some online tutorials.
I successfully made a custom ArrayAdapter as well as the whole ListFragment thing.

**[Code]**

*The list item I created looks like this;*

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:padding="6dip" >
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/img"
        android:src="@drawable/img"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/img"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        android:textSize="36dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/img"
        android:layout_height="42dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/dev_name"
        android:text="TEST"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

*The drawable img;*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/orange" /> 
    <item android:state_activated="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/green" />
    <item android:state_activated="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/red" /> 
</selector>
```

*The custom ArrayAdapter Class;*

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<DeviceTest> {
    private final Context context;
    private final DeviceTest[]deviceList;
    public CustomAdapter(Context context, DeviceTest[]deviceList) {
        super(context, R.layout.listitem,deviceList);
        this.context = context;
        this.deviceList =deviceList;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View listItem = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem, parent, false);
        ImageView img = (ImageView) listItem.findViewById(R.id.img);
        img.setActivated(deviceList[position].isActivated());
        TextView device = (TextView) listItem.findViewById(R.id.dev_name);
        device.setText(deviceList[position].getName());
        return listItem;
    }

}
```

*The custom Fragment Class;*

```
public class MyListFragment extends ListFragment{
private DeviceTest[] deviceList;
private  CustomAdapter customAdapter;
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    deviceList = new DeviceTest[] {new DeviceTest("First"),new DeviceTest("Second")};
    customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(getActivity(),deviceList);
    setListAdapter(customAdapter);
}

@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    customAdapter.getItem(position).setActivated(!customAdapter.getItem(position).isActivated());
    customAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

}

*DeviceTest Object;*

```
public class DeviceTest {
    private String name;
    private boolean activated;
    public DeviceTest(String name){
        this.name = name;
        this.activated = true;
    }

    public void setActivated(boolean activated) {
        this.activated = activated;
    }

    public boolean isActivated() {
        return activated;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

**[Question]**

How would you have the state of the ImageView changed via the onListItemClick method?
 My intention was to have the ImageView initially set to red, when pressed set to orange 
and afterwards to green or red depending on its previous state.

Thanks in advance!

**[Solved]**

Adjusted the code, cheers for the advice!

Comment: It seems like you need to maintain a state inside your object. Then when you press the item associated with the object you have to change the state and call `notifyDataSetChange()` over the adapter. So you should pass an object and not a String, to the adapter

Comment: Dear Joseph, thanks for your contribution both your tip as well as removing the default drawable seemed to have fixed it. I'll update the code to a working version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

            <item android:drawable="@color/orange" android:state_pressed="true"></item>
            <!-- pressed -->
            <item android:drawable="@color/green" android:state_focused="true"></item>
            <!-- focused -->
            <item android:drawable="@color/green"></item>
            <!-- default -->
        </selector>
```

Comment: Dear VipSha, removing the default drawable and what Joseph82 mentioned seemed to have fixed the thing. Thank you for your contribution.